# After deleting a post with pending delete votes, it looks like it has pending undelete votes

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, deleted-answers

Minor bug in the moderator dashboard (`/admin/dashboard`):

[image]

If a post already has pending delete votes from high-rep users, the "delete" button includes a number in brackets to show how many delete votes have already been cast. After I click this button to cast my binding delete vote, the post's display on the dashboard collapses and the button becomes an "undelete" button with **the same figure shown in brackets**, making it look as though there's now that number of pending votes to *un*delete. This is slightly confusing at first, and appears to be a bug.